# Java class not found exceptoin

Tags: java

I have the following path setup

```
  /project/src/Application.java
  /project/src/controllers/Controller.java
  ...
  /project/src/views/ConfigurationView.java
  ...
  /project/development/calendarPicker/DateComboBox.java
```

The main routine is in `Application.java`, and creates a `ConfigurationView` object.  `ConfigurationView` contains a `DateComboBox` object.  The execution error occurs in `Application` when `ConfigurationView` is instantiated.  The error that occurs is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: calenderPicker/DateComboBox.
```

Also, I'm using eclipse.  In `ConfigurationView.java`, if I remove `import calenderPicker.DateComboBox`, it creates errors for `DateComboBox`.  When I right click on one of the errors, and select `import calenderPicker.DateComboBox`, the errors go away until I save the file.  Then, there is an error on `import calenderPicker.DateComboBox` that states "calenderPicker.DateComboBox can not be resolved".

If I search for DateComboBox, it shows up as expected, in

```
/project/development/calendarPicker/DateComboBox.java (18 matches)
/project/src/views/ConfigurationView.java  (8 matches)
```

How do I fix the errrors?

John

Comment: Is it just a typo or do you have `calenderPicker` in one place and `calendarPicker` in others? (note e vs. a)

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add the source path "/project/development/" to your build path. Edit the project properties, goto "Java Build Path" and "Add Folder" development.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go for **Problems** view ,there a list of errors will be given.There you can get the assistance actually what the cause of errors.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest fix is move the class calendarPicker/DateComboBox.java to src dir. Because there are your all source files.

Second proposition to fix this problem can be make development as your source directory in Eclipse